# How to fix TypeError: ''DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed' when trying to loop through to return a dataframe for each team

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

using dataset from https://cdncontribute.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/nba.csv. I want to split this out into a separate dataframe per team. But I am getting the TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

Tried using a for loop to iterate through the teams and run get_group method on each team in order to get a dataframe for each team.

Opened this as a df:

```
NBA_data_csv = pd.read_csv(file, encoding = "cp1252")
NBA_data_csv
```

used the groupby method:

```
by_team = NBA_data_csv.groupby('Team')
```

can see all the groups:

```
by_team.groups
```

now as I can see these individually in a data frame using get_group ie:

```
by_team.get_group('Boston Celtics')
```

I want to split this out into a separate dataframe per team. But I do not want to have to manually type in each team ie: 'Boston Celtics' to get this.

I tried the following but got an error:

```
for team in by_team:
    by_team.get_group(team)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can give more information on *why* you need to split this? There's typically little need, since it's readily accessible through `groupby`. You might be looking for `dict(tuple(NBA_data_csv.groupby('Team')))`

Comment: Hi ALollz, I need to split this so that I can print and manipulate the data more easily with reference only to each individual team. I don't need the other data convoluting it. I'd also like to graph it all separately add columns to only that specific team's dataframe, do team specific calculations and comparison.